# Something's wrong with my scheduledTimer on SpriteKit

Tags: swift, timer, sprite-kit

I'm experimenting a few things with Swift and SpriteKit.

I have 4 images of coins. (coin1,coin2, ...). I want to spawn a random coin at a random position on the screen and let it fade out. I want to repeat this action every 3 seconds. This is the code and it worked fine.

```
    class GameScene: SKScene {

// creating a playable area
let gameArea: CGRect
override init(size: CGSize) {

    let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat = 16.0/9.0
    let playableWidth = size.height / maxAspectRatio
    let gameAreaMargin = (size.width - playableWidth)/2
    gameArea = CGRect(x: gameAreaMargin, y: 270, width: playableWidth, height: size.height - 270)

    super.init(size: size)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


func random() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
}
func random(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return random() * (max-min) + min
}


func spawnAndFadeCoins() -> SKSpriteNode{

    let randNum = arc4random()%4 + 1
    let coin = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "coin\(randNum)")

    if randNum == 4 {
        coin.zPosition = 10
    }
    else {
        coin.zPosition = 5
    }
    coin.name = "coin\(randNum)"
            let randomX = random(min: gameArea.minX + coin.size.width/2,
                         max: gameArea.maxX - coin.size.width/2)
            let randomY = random(min: gameArea.minY + coin.size.height/2,
                         max: gameArea.maxY - coin.size.height/2)
            coin.position = CGPoint(x: randomX, y: randomY)

    let disappear = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 1.0)
    coin.run(SKAction.repeatForever(disappear))
    self.addChild(coin)
    return(coin)

}
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bg")
    background.size = self.size
    background.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
    background.zPosition = 0
    self.addChild(background)

    var _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.spawnAndFadeCoins), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        }
    }
```

However, when I add a label to each coin specifying its name, something weird happens: After every 3 seconds, 3 coins appear simultaneously on the screen. The label is placed on 1 of those 3 coins, and it doesn't even say the coin's name correctly. This is the new code:

```
    class GameScene: SKScene {

// creating a playable area
let gameArea: CGRect
override init(size: CGSize) {

    let maxAspectRatio: CGFloat = 16.0/9.0
    let playableWidth = size.height / maxAspectRatio
    let gameAreaMargin = (size.width - playableWidth)/2
    gameArea = CGRect(x: gameAreaMargin, y: 270, width: playableWidth, height: size.height - 270)

    super.init(size: size)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}


func random() -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
}
func random(min: CGFloat, max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return random() * (max-min) + min
}


func spawnAndFadeCoins() -> SKSpriteNode{

    let randNum = arc4random()%4 + 1
    let coin = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "coin\(randNum)")

    if randNum == 4 {
        coin.zPosition = 10
    }
    else {
        coin.zPosition = 5
    }
    coin.name = "coin\(randNum)"

            let randomX = random(min: gameArea.minX + coin.size.width/2,
                         max: gameArea.maxX - coin.size.width/2)
    let randomY = random(min: gameArea.minY + coin.size.height/2,
                         max: gameArea.maxY - coin.size.height/2)
    coin.position = CGPoint(x: randomX, y: randomY)


    let disappear = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 1.0)
    coin.run(SKAction.repeatForever(disappear))
    self.addChild(coin)
    return(coin)

}

func spawnAndFadeLabels() -> SKLabelNode{
    let label = SKLabelNode()
    label.text = "\(spawnAndFadeCoins().name)"
    label.zPosition = 15
    label.color = SKColor.white()
    label.fontSize = 60
    label.position = spawnAndFadeCoins().position

    let disappear2 = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 1.0)
    label.run(SKAction.repeatForever(disappear2))


    self.addChild(label)
    return(label)
}




override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bg")
    background.size = self.size
    background.position = CGPoint(x:self.frame.size.width/2, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
    background.zPosition = 0
    self.addChild(background)

    var _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.spawnAndFadeCoins), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    var _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(GameScene.spawnAndFadeLabels), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)



        }
    }
```

Can you help me solve this mystery? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you called `spawnAndFadeCoins` *two more times* in `spawnAndFadeLabels`:

```
func spawnAndFadeLabels() -> SKLabelNode{
    let label = SKLabelNode()
    label.text = "\(spawnAndFadeCoins().name)" <-- here!
    label.zPosition = 15
    label.color = SKColor.white()
    label.fontSize = 60
    label.position = spawnAndFadeCoins().position <-- and here!

    let disappear2 = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 1.0)
    label.run(SKAction.repeatForever(disappear2))


    self.addChild(label)
    return(label)
}
```

I think one thing you can do to solve it is this:

Have only one timer:

```
runAction(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3), SKAction.run(spawnAndFadeCoins)])))
```

I used `SKAction`s here because it is not recommended to use `Timer` in spritekit.

Now only `spawnAndFadeCoins` will be called once every three seconds. Then, change `spawnAndFadeLabels` to:

```
func spawnAndFadeLabels(of node: SKSpriteNode) -> SKLabelNode{
    let label = SKLabelNode()
    label.text = "\(node.name)"
    label.zPosition = 15
    label.color = SKColor.white()
    label.fontSize = 60
    label.position = node.position

    let disappear2 = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 1.0)
    label.run(SKAction.repeatForever(disappear2))
    self.addChild(label)
    return(label)
}
```

Change `spawnAndFadeCoins` to:

```
func spawnAndFadeCoins() -> SKSpriteNode{

    let randNum = arc4random()%4 + 1
    let coin = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "coin\(randNum)")

    if randNum == 4 {
        coin.zPosition = 10
    }
    else {
        coin.zPosition = 5
    }
    coin.name = "coin\(randNum)"

            let randomX = random(min: gameArea.minX + coin.size.width/2,
                         max: gameArea.maxX - coin.size.width/2)
    let randomY = random(min: gameArea.minY + coin.size.height/2,
                         max: gameArea.maxY - coin.size.height/2)
    coin.position = CGPoint(x: randomX, y: randomY)


    let disappear = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 1.0)
    coin.run(SKAction.repeatForever(disappear))
    self.addChild(coin)
    spawnAndFadeLabels(of: coin) <-- This line is added!
    return(coin)

}
```

I think this is want you want.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much :)

Comment: @DatBoringName If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!